# Am i using session correctly?

Tags: php, session

Am I using session correctly? Or doing it this way is bad? Is there a better way of using session for securing web application

this is my php code

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_login(?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30); 
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row){
        $_SESSION['Login_username'] = $_username;
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
```

and this is the code for checking sessions

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Login_username'])) {

    return true;
}
else{
    header("location: login.php");
        exit;
}
```

I've read somewhere that it's a good idea to save session on the database.

I'm going to save it to the database. How am i going to do that? 
After a successful login, I want insert the session to the database?

And how will i use the saved session  in my  database?

Some says its better `this` way and some says its better `that` way. And now I'm confused.

Comment: I think, you are not protected against sql injection.

Comment: what? im not protected against sql injection? how? please elaborate. or point out the code. where sql injection is possible. thank you

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I'm not seeing the SQL injection here. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

PHP saves sessions into files, in a directory which you can find using [session-save-path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) function (or the setting mentioned on that page).

You are using the session correctly, considering you always call `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`.

Just think of `$_SESSION` as a normal array, that is automatically filled for each user by PHP. Practically anything can be applied to that, like `unset`, `isset` ...

Saving sessions into database is possible too, as many frameworks provide that. Some of them rolled out their own implementation just to handle it better, but some are using the default PHP provider.

As Jay C's answer mentioned, you save session into database when you have a distributed application, that is running on multiple nodes. Although that can be handled using shared filesystems too (just share the mentioned path on all nodes).

Anyway, to find out how to implement your own session handler, see [PHP documentations](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php).

To find out the default handlers provided by your php, look for "Registered save handlers" in the output of `phpinfo()`.

If you just *heard* that saving session into database is a better idea, you don't probably need it. Trust me, saving session into database rises a lot of problems that you wouldn't face when using filesystem. Databases are tricky to handle under load, and having sessions in database can easily put database under load. Just don't do it unless you are totally sure you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Only reason you would need to store sessions in the database is if you had multiple servers and a cross-server login script or something alike.

Comment: i thought its safe. thank you. so in order to make my web application safe is by integrating the code. in the example. am i right? and how can i make sure that the application is safe in sql injection. i thought im using prepared statement?

Answer (score -2):

You've asked too many different questions at once.

**Am I using session correctly?** yes.

**doing it this way is bad?** no.

**Is there a better way of using session for securing web application?** not really.

**I'm going to save it to the database. How am i going to do that?** however you want to.

**After a successful login, I want insert the session to the database?** No.

**And how will i use the saved session in my database?** You use it exactly as you already do, with $_SESSION, and session_start().

If you want to store sessions in the database, look at "session_set_save_handler" and "SessionHandlerInterface" in the PHP documentation.  These dictate to PHP how the session data is loaded and saved, they have nothing to do with how the $_SESSION var is used -- which is the same regardless of how/where the session data is stored.